# control two motors with arduino

Tags: arduino, avr, motordriver

im using a arduino with TB6612FNG motor driver to control two dc motors. Im following this link http://bildr.org/2012/04/tb6612fng-arduino/  the problem im having is when i run the code below the motors do not run. If I comment out "move(2, 255, 1)" then one of the motors spins. why wont both motors spin? any help?

//motor A connected between A01 and A02
//motor B connected between B01 and B02

```
int STBY = 10; //standby

//Motor A
int PWMA = 3; //Speed control 
int AIN1 = 9; //Direction
int AIN2 = 8; //Direction

//Motor B
int PWMB = 5; //Speed control
int BIN1 = 11; //Direction
int BIN2 = 12; //Direction

void setup(){
  pinMode(STBY, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(PWMA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AIN2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(PWMB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BIN2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  move(1, 255, 1); //motor 1, full speed, left
  move(2, 255, 1); //motor 2, full speed, left


}


void move(int motor, int speed, int direction){
//Move specific motor at speed and direction
//motor: 0 for B 1 for A
//speed: 0 is off, and 255 is full speed
//direction: 0 clockwise, 1 counter-clockwise

  digitalWrite(STBY, HIGH); //disable standby

  boolean inPin1 = LOW;
  boolean inPin2 = HIGH;

  if(direction == 1){
    inPin1 = HIGH;
    inPin2 = LOW;
  }

  if(motor == 1){
    digitalWrite(AIN1, inPin1);
    digitalWrite(AIN2, inPin2);
    analogWrite(PWMA, speed);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(BIN1, inPin1);
    digitalWrite(BIN2, inPin2);
    analogWrite(PWMB, speed);
  }
}

void stop(){
//enable standby  
  digitalWrite(STBY, LOW); 
}
```

Comment: Try setting the second motor in the other direction.  If that makes both spin, maybe you have mixed up the wiring - try swapping one wire between the two motors.

Comment: The code looks fine, maybe there is something wrong with your circuit or with power supply.

Comment: Sounds like not enough power to drive both motors. Trying a lower PWM value. Can the battery drive both motors when hooked up directly? What is the voltage?

Comment: @UncleO- i fixed the problem, they are both spinning but one motor is running slower. When i hook both motors to the power source with out the motor driver they both run at equal speeds. But when i use the motor driver one is slower

Comment: The motor driver has a limit on how much current can run through it. (0.9 A per motor at 100% duty. More at lower duty cycles.) You may be hitting up against that limit. You can still compensate by calibrating the two motors duty cycles, and limiting how hard you push them. You could also use one driver board for each motor.

Comment: @UncleO- how do i lower the duty cycle

Comment: Use a number lower than 255 in the `move()` function. This number is the proportion of time the power is on (out of 255).